# mpirun is unable to import installed packages

Tags: segmentation-fault, openmpi, modulenotfounderror, qiskit

I am running `qiskit` code which execute fine when I invoke it with `python3` but when called with mpirun, it executes `SegmentationFault Error`mentioning some `Permission Errors`. I run command as root , it says `ModuleNotFoundError` (which is already installed and working with normal execution - worth mentioning is this error started coming after restart)

```
sudo mpirun --allow-run-as-root python3 test-mpi.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dell/qiskit-aer-main/demo-files/test-mpi.py", line 3, in <module>
from qiskit.providers.aer import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'qiskit.providers.aer'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dell/qiskit-aer-main/demo-files/test-mpi.py", line 3, in <module>
from qiskit.providers.aer import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'qiskit.providers.aer'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dell/qiskit-aer-main/demo-files/test-mpi.py", line 3, in <module>
from qiskit.providers.aer import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'qiskit.providers.aer'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dell/qiskit-aer-main/demo-files/test-mpi.py", line 3, in <module>
from qiskit.providers.aer import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'qiskit.providers.aer'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Primary job  terminated normally, but 1 process returned
a non-zero exit code. Per user-direction, the job has been aborted.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun detected that one or more processes exited with non-zero status, thus causing
the job to be terminated. The first process to do so was:

Process name: [[51849,1],0]
Exit code:    1
```

Below is code along with normal output

```
from qiskit import *
from qiskit.circuit.library import *
from qiskit.providers.aer import *
sim = AerSimulator(method='statevector')
shots = 100
depth=10
qubits = 35
circuit = transpile(QuantumVolume(qubits, depth, seed=0),
backend=sim,
optimization_level=0)
circuit.measure_all()
result = execute(circuit,sim,shots=shots,seed_simulator=12345).result()
if result.to_dict()['metadata']['mpi_rank'] == 0:
    print (result.to_dict()['metadata'])
```

Here is normal output case:

```
python3 test-mpi.py

{'time_taken_execute': 0.222742047, 'mpi_rank': 0, 'time_taken_parameter_binding': 8.8427e-05, 'num_mpi_processes': 1, 'num_processes_per_experiments': 1, 'omp_enabled': True, 'max_gpu_memory_mb': 0, 'max_memory_mb': 15903, 'parallel_experiments': 1}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by manually adding paths in code:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/dell/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/')
```

mpirun was having some issues with python virtual environment and couldn't load paths by itself.